# How to create pallet errors for sudo that show up on the Polkadot JS apps interface?

Tags: sudo, polkadot-js

[Repost from stackoverflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70766123/how-to-create-pallet-errors-that-show-up-on-the-polkadot-js-apps-interface)

So I've been at my wits' end for quite some time regarding `#[pallet::error]` showing up on Polkadot JS apps interface when calling a fallible function from sudo. So as I've come to understand following substrate kitties tutorial that we require to return a `DispatchResult` out of our dispatchable calls and after doing so, I have a case where I am not seeing any errors on my apps interface, although the operation does fail successfully as I don't see any mistakes on the balancesToAccount hashmap.

This code compiles fine.

```
    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1))]
        /// Allow only Root to mint new tokens & transfer it to some benefactor account
        /// Set a hard uppper limit on the total number of tokens in supply
        pub fn mint(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            #[pallet::compact] amount: <T as Config>::Balance,
            benefactor: T::AccountId,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            // Check if sudo call
            ensure_root(origin.clone())?;

            // Check if existing amount doesn't overflow MaxTokenSupply
Error   |---->  Self::does_adding_overflow_maxtokensupply(amount)?;
            
            // Check if Benefactor already has funds
            let previous_balance = <BalanceToAccount<T>>::try_get(&benefactor).unwrap_or_default();
            let final_balance = previous_balance.saturating_add(amount);
            <BalanceToAccount<T>>::insert(&benefactor, final_balance);
            Self::deposit_event(Event::MintedNewSupply(amount));
            Ok(().into())
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have a helper function that will check if minting `amount` causes a overflow to the total token supply. And that function is defined here:

```
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        fn does_adding_overflow_maxtokensupply(amount: T::Balance) -> Result<(), Error<T>> {
            let total_already_minted: T::Balance = BalanceToAccount::<T>::iter_values().sum();
            let new_supply =
                total_already_minted.checked_add(&amount).ok_or(Error::<T>::MintTypeOverflow)?;
            if new_supply <= T::MaxTokenSupply::get() {
                Ok(())
            } else {
                Err(Error::<T>::MintCausingTotalSupplyOverflow)
            }
        }
    }
```

I was expected `?` to automagically cast the Error into something `DispatchResult` can work with, but I'm not sure if that's happening on this line:

```
Self::does_adding_overflow_maxtokensupply(amount)?;
```

Here's what Polkadot JS apps shows when I give it a number greater than max supply :
[image]
Next I check whether that balance went through (It shouldn't), and indeed it didn't go through.
[image: Alice's Balance not updated]

What I would like the apps interface is to show an error rejecting such requests as it does in case of `BadOrigin`. How can I achieve this?

Edit #1: **I should mention that this function is only callable by `sudo`,** if that makes a difference. I can see extrinsic Errors on other functions, except this one.

Comment: @NukeManDan there done. have fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid at the moment the UI does not show these errors. This seems to be a UX fail but I am hopeful that we can fix it. This is the issue to watch:

https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/3072

(The sudo call is successfully invoking the parameter so it is a successful extrinsic even if there are inner errors - same woes with utils.batch, incomplete xcm messages etc.)